# Solidity code not transferring ether in Javascript VM environment

Tags: solidity

I am trying my hands on a program which transfers test ethers from one account to other on remix ide using javascript VM environment. I am unable to see funds getting transferred to beneficiary account.

I have put diagnostic code as well which prints the contract current balance but it always prints 0.

```
pragma solidity <=0.5.7;
contract MultiSigWallet{
    address payable private owner;
    address payable private  beneficiary;
    uint private minApprovers ;
    uint private currentApprovals;
    mapping(address => bool) approvedBy;
    mapping(address =>bool) isApprover;
    uint public contractBalance;

    constructor  (address payable _beneficiary, address [] memory  _approvers, int32 _minApprovers) public payable{
        require(_approvers.length > 0 && _minApprovers > 0,"At least one approver is required!");
        require(_approvers.length >= minApprovers,"Number of minimum approvers cannot be more than total approvers count");
        owner   = msg.sender;
        beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        for(uint i = 0;i<_approvers.length;i++){
            isApprover[_approvers[i]]= true;
        }

    }

    function approve () public{
        require(isApprover[msg.sender],"Not an Approver");
        if(!approvedBy[msg.sender]){
         approvedBy[msg.sender] = true;
         currentApprovals++;
        }
        if(currentApprovals== minApprovers){
            beneficiary.send(address(this).balance);
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    }

    function getContractBalance () public payable returns( uint){
       contractBalance =  address(this).balance;
    }
    function reject() public {
        require(isApprover[msg.sender],"Not an approver!");
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }


}
```

if i provide beneficiary address as a1, list of approvers as a2,a3 and i invoke the constructor with a4 by putting 10 ethers in the value field, i can see 10 ether reduction in a4 balance.

Next after approving from accounts a2, a3, i am expecting the balance of a1 to swell by 10 ethers and balance of contract turns 0.

However i don't see a change in a1 balance and contract balance is always 0.

Can someone explain what i am doing wrong or if any gaps in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like `minApprovers = _minApprovers` in the constructor. Otherwise `minApprovers` is always `0`, and your `==` check will always fail because the first successful call to `approve` will make `currentApprovals == 1`.